# Beamer theme definition: redefine footer for certain frames

Tags: beamer, header-footer, package-writing, themes

How do I remove / change the footer at certain slides in my theme `.sty` file?
I basically want to avoid using `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}` in my `.tex`. E.g. on the title slide / toc / section slide...

## Failed attempts

### Using `\newif`

```latex
\newif\ifbeamer@test@title
\beamer@test@titlefalse

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}{
  \beamer@test@titletrue
  <...>
  \beamer@test@titlefalse
}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{test}{
  \ifbeamer@test@title
  \else
    <...>
  \fi
}
```

## Minimal Working Example

Here a reduced MWE only considering the title page, however the solution should be general enough such that it can also be used for the table of content / section slides

`cat beamerthemetest.sty`

```latex
\mode<presentation>
%% goes to inner theme
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}
{
    \beamer@test@titletrue
    {
      \vspace{42pt}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
          \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
          \else
          \par\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle
          \fi
      \end{beamercolorbox}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
      \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
  \beamer@test@titlefalse
}

%% goes to outer theme

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{test}
{
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, dp=1mm, ht=3.5mm
                             , leftskip=1mm, rightskip=1mm
                            ]{footline}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%

        \makebox[240pt][l]{
          \insertshorttitle\ - \insertsectionhead\ %
          \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\relax\else%
          - \insertsubsectionhead%
          \fi
          }
        \hfill\makebox[20pt][r]{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\mode<all>
```

with the `test.tex`

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{test}
\author{whoami} 
\title{title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{abc}
\begin{frame}{abc}
cde
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for `\begin{frame}[plain]` or I missed something ?

Comment: That is a possibility however I would like this to happen automatically and solved at the .sty file level. It should also work for e.g. `\frame{\sectionpage}`.

Comment: Well you could have `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} <content> \setbeamertemplate{footline}{theme}` for some specific content to disable the footline locally. This should work either in the .sty or the .tex

Comment: I defined an optional footline in the .sty, however I can only set this template in the .tex file. It seems to be ignored when putting it in the first line of the defined titlepage template.

Comment: Moreover, the defined if seem to be ignored. Any ideas why?

Comment: I just tested your code and it does not compile at the moment. You have a additional `/fi` and `\beamer@test@titletrue` is not known to `beamer`

Comment: Ohh, sorry for that, I removed the `\fi`. I however have no idea why `\beamer@test@titletrue` throws an error. For me it compiles just fine.

Comment: Did you try the solution below?

Comment: I did, and it also does the trick. Any clues about the `\newif` issue? This would add a great deal of flexibility to your solution.

Comment: Frankly I have no idea, it does not seem too far-fetched, but I would not use it. The title page can be set independently and if you also want to handle `\tableofcontents` you can use the `\AtBeginSection` snippet. That is what I use in my themes all the time

Comment: any news ?????????

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, I am not convinced this is the best approach though.

The `.tex`

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{test}
\author{whoami} 
\title{title}

\begin{document}

\newmaketitle

\section{abc}
\begin{frame}{abc}
cde
\end{frame} 
\section{def}
\begin{frame}{def}
fgf
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

The `.sty`

```
\mode<presentation>
%% goes to inner theme
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}
{
    %\beamer@test@titletrue
    {
      \vspace{42pt}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
          \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
          \else
          \par\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle
          \fi
      \end{beamercolorbox}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
      \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
}

\newcommand{\newmaketitle}{
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[default]
  \begin{frame}
    \maketitle
  \end{frame}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[test]
}

%% goes to outer theme

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{test}
{
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, dp=1mm, ht=3.5mm
                             , leftskip=1mm, rightskip=1mm
                            ]{footline}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%

        \makebox[240pt][l]{
          \insertshorttitle\ - \insertsectionhead\ %
          \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\relax\else%
          - \insertsubsectionhead%
          \fi
          }
        \hfill\makebox[20pt][r]{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[default]
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
  \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[test]
}


\mode<all>
```